# About Zeck and Ender

Tags: enders-game

Just reread "A War of Gifts" and something about Zeck make me wonder. He just an meat shield (or not at all) to be shoot at in Battle Room - he just fly around and **NEVER** shoot his weapon

> It took quite a while before anyone noticed that Zeck never actually hit anybody with his
>   weapon. In every battle, he was zero for zero.

And look at Ender after his first game with Salamander

> An interesting side effect of the battle was that Ender emerged at the top of the soldier efficiecies list. Since he hadn't fired a shot, he had a perfect record on shooting-- no misses at all.

Well, my question is how both not fire a single shot, Zeck "was listed with zero effectiveness"? 
    For more clarification about my question, i want to know how can it happen, Zeck at least on top of "record on shooting" like Ender - he will be the best soldier with shooting's accuracy, so he cant be zero effective
    Have i missing something? Or this is another "normal thing" because OSC too carelessly like other books about timeline, character's age... ?

Comment: Haven't read the book, but your quote states that Zeck never hit someone, not that he never shot. That means he could have shot plenty, but missed all while Ender never shot and logically never missed. Also Han shot first.

Comment: @Zikato i have thought about that but when i reread it a lot of times, i relize he actually never shot - "In every battle, he was zero for zero", 0/0 mean he dont shot right? or i misunderstanding?

Comment: After Ender defaulted to the top rating by not shooting, didn't the Teachers change the algorithm for the ratings?

Comment: I think in this context 0 for 0 means he never shot anybody and was never shot by anybody, not that he hit people 0 times out of 0 shots. I haven't actually read A War of Gifts though, so I could be wrong

Comment: my question get downvote because no one can answer LOL; but @Gedgar Zeck older than Ender about 1 year (Zeck about 9 when Ender tranfer to Rat) so he can on top the whole time before Ender emerge; and with 'childcat15' if what you say is true so he more effevtive than Ender and anyone else in the school's history

Comment: Your question got downvoted because some people don't have a clue what downvote button is for :(

Comment: IMO it have long time between the date release of two book, so Mr Card may not remember all details - he already mention this at the end in some book (not remember correctly which book) so that why he need help from forum(s) etc... to help him finish later book without too much opposite with the old one(s), but of course still have somethings not fully explain or different like this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the second thing that contributed to Ender's ranking.

> And since he had never been eliminated or disabled, his percentage there was excellent.

Ender was ranked the #1 soldier because he had a perfect shooting record AND he wasn't disabled or eliminated.

As a "meat shield" Zeck is presumably getting disabled or eliminated every single battle. It is possible Zeck also as a "perfect" record on shooting, but soldier performance is based on both accuracy and your ability to stay alive.

*Note: This is all taking place in a world where 0 / 0 = 100%*

Comment: great, thank for the answer, this make me look from different angle and understand why Zeck is "zero effectiveness"